# How to update an type with a new enum and let an existing column use the new value in postgres

Tags: database, postgresql, types, enums

I have a use case of adding a new enum into an existing type, so I have used this command to add the enum :

```
`ALTER TYPE type_1 ADD VALUE 'NEW_VALUE';`
```

I have an existing table, let's say table1, with a column column1 that uses this type_1 in one of its columns, but when I try to insert a record into this table1 with column1 value as the NEW_VALUE that I've just added, I get an error saying:

```
ERROR:  invalid input value for enum type_1: "NEW_VALUE"
LINE 1: "table1" where "type_1"='NEW_VALUE"
```

Does anyone know why this is happening?

I know that the ALTER TYPE command worked since the output of

```
`SELECT enum_range(NULL::settlement_instruction_type)`
```

gives me the old enums and the new one that I've just added.

What can I do to make the records which have this NEW_VALUE get inserted into the table?